# Multiple Entity arguments in Google Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

How can I pass more than one Entity from a client to a Google Cloud Endpoint?

For example, passing a single Entity is easily done in an Endpoint api source file in the server:

```
public class SomeEndpoint {
...
   @ApiMethod(...)
   public MyEntity someMethod(MyEntity someEntity) {
   ...
   }
...
}
```

then in a client I could easily call

```
endpoint.someMethod(someEntity).execute()
```

But, what if I want to pass two entities to an endpoint?, like this:

```
 @ApiMethod(...)
 public MyEntity otherMethod(MyEntity someEntity, MyEntity someOtherEntity) {
    ...
 }
```

this doesn't work, GPE only generates an endpoint library with a single MyEntity argument.

Is it possible to pass multiple Entity arguments?

Thanks.

Comment: Will it be not possible to combine the different fields in the two split entities into a single entity itself? In your server code, you can get the single entity and process the 2 categories of fields differently.

Comment: Thanks @tony.  Yes, I suppose I could create a new entity that combines the two somehow, but I'm trying to avoid that. I'd also like to know the limitations of an endpoint in this regard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't send multiple entity types in the body of your request. You'll need to create a wrapper entity that contains those two entities, e.g.:

```
class MyWrapperEntity {
  MyEntity someEntity;
  MyOtherEntity someOtherEntity;
  // ...
}
```

However, that's not what your example shows (the entities are the same type). Use a `List<MyEntity>` or `Map<String, MyEntity>` inside of a collection entity instead, e.g.:

```
class MyEntityCollection {
  List<MyEntity> items;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dan.  I tried that since I am using two entities of the same type, and Eclipse allowed it to be built using List<MyEntity>, but the resulting method in the generated Endpoint API had no arguments at all.  It ignores List<MyEntity>, and it ignores anything after the first MyEntity if you have more than one.

Comment: Dan, are you still essentially suggesting that I create a "wrapper" entity to solve this problem?  If so, it's not clear how I can create an AppEngine entity that wraps multiple entities.

Comment: What isn't clear? Entities are objects. An Endpoint method accepts a maximum of one entity in the body (though that entity may itself have properties that are objects or scalar types). Both of the examples I provided demonstrate this.

Comment: Yes, I had confused the issue with storing Entities that contain multiple entities in the Datastore, but that is not the issue here, as you point out.  You can simply create a wrapper entity as you show, then strip out whatever is necessary in the endpoint service, then store them separately as needed.

Comment: Due to this restriction, is it thus better datastore API modeling practice to NOT pass in multiple entities to an API method? Should one strive to create a datastore model that avoids that?

Comment: Well here is what kind of sucks, if you use a wrapper class, you can't really use the web based API explorer to test out your methods. You can't pass in anything to the request body (like you can't select anything from the drop down). Not sure if it is a bug or what but this is what I found.

Comment: @aez please help here stackoverflow.com/q/42371135/3671509

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'named' annotation...

```
@ApiMethod(name = "sendStuff")
public void sendStuff( @Named("clientId") String clientId, @Named("stuff") String stuff )
```

And for android, the client code would look like this

```
SendStuff sl = service.sendStuff( clientId, stuff );
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, you can surely do that with primitive types like String and Long, etc., but my problem is using multiple Entities as arguments.  @Named will not work for those.