# How to create a setter for a GeoPt field of a JDO entity in App Engine datastore such that it shows up in the endpoint client library?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, jdo, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a GeoPt field for a JDO entity on App Engine and I created the following setter for it:

```
public void setLocation(Float latitude,Float longitude){
    location=new GeoPt(latitude, longitude);
}
```

However, when I generate the Cloud Endpoints client library through Google Plugin for Eclipse, this method does not show up in the list of methods available for this entity.

How should I modify the setter such that the client library creates an endpoint for it?

Comment: Is it not possible to pass two parameters to a setter for a field of a JDO obect?

Comment: As I said, I created this method in the Entity class of the backend App Engine project, but when I generated the Cloud Endpoints client library for the App Engine project, all the setter and getter methods of the Entity had a corresponding endpoint method except this one. My guess is this is because the method has two parameters instead of one.

Comment: You mean just like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450472/multiple-entity-arguments-in-google-cloud-endpoints