# Is it possible to pass two parameters to a setter method for an App Engine entity through JDO?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

Will such a setter method for an App Engine entity in JDO work? It has been passed two parameters instead of one.

```
public void setLocation(Float latitude,Float longitude){
    location=new GeoPt(latitude, longitude);
}
```

If we can't pass two parameters to a setter method, can we achieve this through some other means like passing a JSONObject that has both these fields?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a setter for a GeoPt field of a JDO entity in App Engine datastore such that it shows up in the endpoint client library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499347/how-to-create-a-setter-for-a-geopt-field-of-a-jdo-entity-in-app-engine-datastore)

Comment: Problem is nothing to do with JDO. This is Google EndPoints. JDO puts zero restrictions on classes